# SQL select join the row with max (arithmatic(value1, value2))

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a Trade system where people can make offer on the items they want. There are two currencies in the system, gold and silver. 100 silver = 1 gold. Note that people can make offers the same price as others, so there could be duplicate highest offer price.

Table structure looks roughly like this

```
Trade table  
ID


TradeOffer table  
ID
UserID
TradeID references Trade(ID)  
GoldOffer  
SilverOffer
```

I want to display to the user a list of trades sorted by the highest offer price whenever they do a search with constraint.

The Ideal output would be similar to this

```
Trade.ID    TradeOffer.ID    HighestGoldOffer    HighestSilverOffer    UserID
```

where `HighestGoldOffer`  and  `HighestSilverOffer` are the value of `GoldOffer` and `SilverOffer` column of the `Offer` with highest (GoldOffer * 100 + SilverOffer) and `UserID` is the user who made the offer

I know I can run 2 separate queries, one to retrieve all the Trades that satisfies all the constraint and extract all the ID to run another query to get the highest offer, but I am a perfectionist so I would prefer to do it with one sql instead of two.

I could just select all offers that are (GoldOffer * 100 + SilverOffer) = MAX (GoldOffer * 100 + SilverOffer) but this would possibly return duplicated Trade if there are multiple people offered the same price. Also there could be nobody offered on the Trade yet so GoldOffer and SilverOffer will be empty, I would still like to show the Trade as no offer when this happened.

Hope I made myself clear and thanks for any help

Comment: you should search for windowing functions, i think this may be what you're looking for. (assuming your sql language supports this)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Currently using SQLServer, but this might need to migrate to Mysql

Comment: @Beta033 can you explain a bit more? I dont think what I am reading is what I am looking for.

Comment: I am going to remove my answer until I have time to properly select one result per window so others won't be mislead.

Comment: If there are duplicate (highest) offers do you want to display them both or not?  If not, then which UserID do you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

**Model and test data**

```
CREATE TABLE Trade (ID INT)
CREATE TABLE TradeOffer
(
    ID INT,
    UserID INT,
    TradeID INT,
    GoldOffer INT,
    SilverOffer INT
)

INSERT Trade VALUES (1), (2), (3)
INSERT TradeOffer VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 10, 15),
    (2, 2, 1, 11, 15),
    (3, 1, 2, 10, 16),
    (4, 2, 2, 10, 16)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    [TradeID],
    [TradeOfferID],
    [HighestGoldOffer],
    [HighestSilverOffer],
    [UserID]
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.ID AS [TradeID],
        tOffer.ID AS [TradeOfferID],
        tOffer.GoldOffer AS [HighestGoldOffer],
        tOffer.SilverOffer AS [HighestSilverOffer],
        tOffer.[UserID],
        RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY t.ID
            ORDER BY (([GoldOffer] * 100) + [SilverOffer]) DESC
        ) AS [Rank]
    FROM Trade t
    LEFT JOIN TradeOffer tOffer
        ON tOffer.TradeID = t.ID
) x
WHERE [Rank] = 1
```

**Result**

[image]